# Problems with displaying data in datagrid view column

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, date, datagrid

I am using datagrid view in a windows form application. I have several data grids that display a date date column. When I display my data, the date shows correctly but is always followed by  '00:00:00'. How can I change it to only display the date as 'dd/mm'yyyy'.

I build my datagrid as follows:

```
     //Populate customers datagrid view
    private void displayInGrid_Customers(string sqlcmd)
    {
        customersDataGridView.Rows.Clear();

        connect.Open();

        command.Connection = connect;
        command.CommandText = sqlcmd;

        reader = command.ExecuteReader();


        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // add a row ( get index )
            int arow = customersDataGridView.Rows.Add();

            // datagridname.row[index].cells.value = reader[table].tostring()
            customersDataGridView.Rows[arow].Cells[0].Value = reader["Customer_ID"].ToString();
            customersDataGridView.Rows[arow].Cells[1].Value = reader["Forename"].ToString();
            customersDataGridView.Rows[arow].Cells[2].Value = reader["Surname"].ToString();
            customersDataGridView.Rows[arow].Cells[3].Value = reader["Address"].ToString();
            customersDataGridView.Rows[arow].Cells[4].Value = reader["Town"].ToString();
            customersDataGridView.Rows[arow].Cells[5].Value = reader["Postcode"].ToString();
            customersDataGridView.Rows[arow].Cells[6].Value = reader["Date_Of_Birth"].ToString();
            customersDataGridView.Rows[arow].Cells[7].Value = reader["Phone_Number"].ToString();
            customersDataGridView.Rows[arow].Cells[8].Value = reader["Email"].ToString();
            customersDataGridView.Rows[arow].Cells[9].Value = reader["Current_Rental"].ToString(); 
            customersDataGridView.Sort(Surname, ListSortDirection.Ascending);
        }
        reader.Close();
        connect.Close();
    }

    //Display all customers button
    private void button_view_all_customers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        command.CommandText = "SELECT CUSTOMERS.Customer_ID, CUSTOMERS.Forename, CUSTOMERS.Surname, CUSTOMERS.Address, "
        + "CUSTOMERS.Town, CUSTOMERS.Postcode, CUSTOMERS.Date_Of_Birth, CUSTOMERS.Phone_Number, CUSTOMERS.Email, CUSTOMERS.Current_Rental "
        + "from CUSTOMERS LEFT JOIN STOCK ON CUSTOMERS.Current_Rental = STOCK.Product_ID";
        string cmd = command.CommandText;
        displayInGrid_Customers(cmd);
```

Also, I have another problem in a different datagrid. This one has a payment column and when I originally created the table in access, the data in the column was like '£4.99' and right justified as expected but when I display it, there is no '£' symbol and it is left justified.

Code for that datagrid is:

```
    //Populate payments datagrid view
    private void displayInGrid_Payments(string sqlcmd)
    {
        paymentsDataGridView.Rows.Clear();

        connect.Open();

        command.Connection = connect;
        command.CommandText = sqlcmd;

        reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // add a row ( get index )
            int arow = paymentsDataGridView.Rows.Add();

            paymentsDataGridView.Rows[arow].Cells[0].Value = reader["Customer_ID"].ToString();
            paymentsDataGridView.Rows[arow].Cells[1].Value = reader["Payment"].ToString();
            paymentsDataGridView.Rows[arow].Cells[2].Value = reader["Payment_Date"].ToString();

        }
        reader.Close();
        connect.Close();
    }

    //Display all payments
      private void button_display_payments_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        command.CommandText = "SELECT PAYMENTS.Customer_ID, PAYMENTS.Payment, PAYMENTS.Payment_Date "
        + "from PAYMENTS LEFT JOIN CUSTOMERS ON PAYMENTS.Customer_ID = CUSTOMERS.Customer_ID";
        string cmd = command.CommandText;
        displayInGrid_Payments(cmd);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part try:

```
customersDataGridView.Rows[arow].Cells[6].Value = ((DateTime)reader["Date_Of_Birth"]).ToShortDateString()
```

And for the second part try:

<strike>paymentsDataGridView.Rows[arow].Cells[1].Value = reader["Payment"].ToString("C");</strike>

```
paymentsDataGridView.Rows[arow].Cells[1].Value = String.Format("{0:C}", decimal.Parse(reader["Payment"].ToString()));
```

If it still gives error, try changing decimal for double, although for money and currency I would avoid double because of rounding errors it could give.

Comment: That worked perfectly for my first problem, thank you very, very much!

Comment: Hi. I'm getting the error 'No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments. Do I maybe need to declare decimal somewhere like the ((DateTime)? I put 'decimal where datetime is in the first example but it didn't work.

Comment: my bad, please check it out now

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you but I'm getting a different error now with this part of the code '((decimal)reader["Current_Cost"].ToString()))'. The error says cannot convert type string to decimal? I appreciate your help! :)

Comment: You sir are a gentleman! All working perfectly now! Thank you very, very much. The project is for my college assignment and I have worked very hard on it but have been struggling with a few things. People like you are a god send. I do have one other problem if you feeling up to it regarding the report viewer tool in VS 2010? If not, no worries and thanks again!